# Pandas to_datetime copying value from previous row when input is blank

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas.to_datetime to convert three columns in a dataframe into a datetime object. The function works fine, but when the values for "year", "month" and "day" are blank or None for a row, Pandas duplicates the date it created in the previous row instead of making the datetime value NaT.  I've even tried setting errors="coerce" and haven't had any luck.

Can someone explain why Pandas is behaving this way or how to fix it?  I've read the documentation for to_datetime, and I'm not seeing anything about this being the default behavior.

**Update**: I did some more debugging and discovered that the unexpected behavior is not occurring with pd.to_datetime.  It occurs when I try to replace nan with None using the replace function.

```
due_date = df[["ID","DUE_DATE_YEAR", "DUE_DATE_MONTH", "DATE_DUE_DAY"]].copy()
due_date.columns = ["ID","year", "month", "day"]
due_date["DUE_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(due_date[["year", "month","day"]],errors="coerce")
#Unexpected behavior occuring at the line below. 
due_date["DUE_DATE_NEW"] = due_date["DUE_DATE_NEW"].replace(np.nan,None)
```

due_date dataframe

| ID | DUE_DATE | year | month | day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-10-24 | 2019 | 10 | 24 |
| 2 | 2019-03-20 | 2019 | 3 | 20 |
| 3 | 2019-03-20 (INCORRECT VALUE) | None | None | None |
| 4 | 2020-02-20 | 2020 | 2 | 20 |
| 5 | 2020-02-20 (INCORRECT VALUE) |  |  |  |

Comment: Interesting. This isn't the behaviour in 1.2.4. What version are you using?

Comment: 1.2.1.  Maybe I should upgrade and see if it fixes itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a [known behavior](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17494#issuecomment-328966324) with pd.replace when trying to replace nan with None.  Changing the argument in replace function to a dictionary fixes the issue.

```
due_date["DUE_DATE_NEW"] = due_date["DUE_DATE_NEW"].replace({np.nan:None})
```